# How can I send an e-mail using C# with an HTML table in the e-mail content?

Tags: c#, html, json

This code was designed to send an HTML table in the e-mail content and an Excel table as an attachment to the e-mail, but it does not work as desired.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace GetRequestProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string username = "abc"; 
                string password = "abc"; 
                string endpoint = "https://abc";

                string jsonData = @"
                {
                    ""TemplateFolder"": ""abc"",
                    ""TemplateNo"": ""001"",
                    ""Channel"": 8,
                    ""CustomerNo"": ""0000"",
                    ""MessageReferenceId"": ""xyz"",
                    ""Priority"": 1,
                    ""PlannedSendingDate"": """",
                    ""VariableList"": [
                        {
                            ""Name"": ""abc"",
                            ""Value"": ""none""
                        }
                    ],
                    ""Subject"": ""trial"",
                    ""To"": ""abc@mail.com"",
                    ""Cc"": null,
                    ""AttachmentList"": [
                        {
                            ""Data"": ""xyz"",
                            ""Name"": ""abc.xlsx""
                        }
                    ],
                    ""HtmlBody"": ""<html><body><table border='1'><tr><th>Product</th><th>Price</th></tr><tr><td>Product 1</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>Product 2</td><td>150</td></tr><tr><td>Product 3</td><td>200</td></tr></table></body></html>""
                }
                ";

                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(jsonData);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Hata: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When this code runs, it only sends an Excel file in the e-mail. How can I update this code so that there is an HTML table in the email content and an Excel file as an attachment?

Comment: It seems your a posting some (random) JSON data to an, for us unknown, endpoint. How do you expect any help if you don't share what the endpoint actually does/is?